# how to determine a subset is closed or not?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Is $A=\{x∈l^2: ||x||≤1\}$ closed subset of $l^2$? Why or why not?

I know here, A is not a vector subspace, so it is not closed under vector addition or scalar multiplication. Does this mean A is also not a closed subset?

By definition, to show A is closed, we need to show that the complement of A in $l^2$ is open. I don't know how to determine whether A is a closed subset or not.

Comment: Closure under multiplication has nothing to do with this.  The definition in the final paragraph is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(x_n)$ be a convergent sequence in $A$ with limit $x$. Then: $||x_n|| \to ||x||$.

Since $||x_n|| \le 1$ for all $n$, we have $||x|| \le 1.$ Hence $x \in A.$

Comment: Thank you so much! So, in this specific question, because the norm is continuous, but what about in other cases? What is the general way to approach this type of question? Can you help me out on another related questions  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4100395/how-to-determine-a-subset-is-closed

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  The norm is continuous,  and it's the inverse image of a closed set, $[0,1] $.

Answer (score 0):

The complement of $A$ is the set $A^\complement=\{x\in\ell^2\mid\|x\|>1\}$. If $x\in A^\complement$ and if $y\in\ell^2$ is such that $\|y-x\|<\|x\|-1$, then$$\|y\|=\|y-x+x\|\geqslant\bigl|\|x|-\|y-x\|\bigr|=\|x\|-\|y-x\|>1,$$and therefore $y\in A^\complement$. So, $A^\complement\supset D(y,\|x\|-1)$. Since this occurs for each $x\in A^\complement$, $A^\complement$ is an open set. So, $A$ is a closed set.